# link_to tag on same page rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

I am trying to link to an element on the same page using link_to

in basic HTML i would do this

```
<a href="#tom">Tom Roche</a>
<a id="tom">Chapter 4</a>
```

I have this in my app

```
<%= link_to 'Tom Roche' %>
<h2>Tom Roche</h2>
```

How would i link these so that when i click on Tom Roche i get taken to the h2 with Tom Roche

I have tried this

```
<%= link_to 'Tom Roche', our_team_path(:anchor => '#tom') %>
<h2><a id="tom">Tom Roche</a></h2>
```

but its not working

Can anyone point out what i need to do, the link_to is throwing me for some reason, even though i know its an a tag

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

link_to can also produce links with anchors or query strings:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried to implement with how i have interpreted your answer but still not working, i have edited my question with what i have tried

Comment: dont worry, removed # from anchor, now works, typo on my part

Answer (score 17):

If you want to link to an anchor tag on the same page the visitor is currently viewing, you can shorten the `link_to` code a bit:

```
<%= link_to "Comment wall", anchor: "wall" %>
```